# How to set disableAutoPanTo in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails and want to stop the map panning when you click on a marker. Currently if you click on a marker it centres itself in the map view.

This looks like it would do the trick but my implementation doesn't seem to work - https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/commit/4c2f437a6252b7555ad5abdedcb5f9d5b08355fe

I've implemented this as follows...

```
this.buildMap = function(markers) {
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { 
    markers: { disableAutoPanTo: true }, //This isn't working
    builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder }
  });
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true, 
      styles: styles
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map'
    }
  }, 
  function() {
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
    google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'click', function() {
      handler.currentInfowindow().close();
    });
  });
};
```

I suspect it's something really obvious but I've spent ages trying to work it out with no luck. Fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`disableAutoPanTo` option doesn't work for me either, but I found a workaround by simply overwriting marker's `panTo` function like so:

```
var markers = handler.addMarkers(markersData);
markers.forEach(function (marker) {
  marker.panTo = function () {};
});
```

This is also good when you want to disable auto pan only for certain markers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `disableAutoPanTo: true` to your internal options like this:

`internal: {
      disableAutoPanTo: true
    }`

Comment: Seems like that would work but for some reason it isn't. I'll update the question with more of my code, perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: Alright! Jus update your code if something is wrong, and I will try to help!

Comment: I've added a larger section of my code in the question above. Don't know if that is enough to spot any problems. I've tried changing `markers:` to `internal:` but this has no affect. Appreciate your help.